# How to retrieve repeating groups from the FIX messages using quickfixj library?

Tags: quickfixj

I have been referring to the quickfixj documentation which states, one can retrieve the repeating groups as given here: https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/repeating_groups.html. But
the given approach is not working in the acceptor, though it is able to extract the repeating groups, when parsed in the sender itself. On trying to fetch the repeating groups, it gives the  fails with the Exception : "Method threw, Quickfix.FieldNotFoundException". Kindly suggest on the same.

```
// FIX50SP2.modified.xml for adding custom message 

<!--In the message declaration section--->
<value enum="CZ" description="MYSAMPLEMESSAGE"/>

    enter code here

<!--In the message definition section--->
<message name="MySampleMessage" msgtype="CZ" msgcat="app">
<field name="EntitlementRepId" required="Y"/>
<component name="EntitlementUpdateGrp" required="Y"/>
<field name="Text" required="N"/>
</message>

<!--In the component definition section--->
<component name="EntitlementUpdateGrp">
 <group name="NoPartyEntitlements" required="Y">
   <field name="ListUpdateAction" required="Y"/>
 </group>
</component>

<!--In the field declaration section--->
<field number="1771" name="EntitlementRepId" type="STRING"/>
<field number="1772" name="NoPartyEntitlements" type="NUMINGROUP"/>
 


public class Acceptor extends MessageCracker implements Application{


    public void onMessage(MySampleMessage message,SessionID sessionId)throws Exception
    {
        MySampleMessage.NoPartEntitlements noPartyEntitlements=new MySampleMessage.NoPartEntitlements();
        ListUpdateAction listUpdateAction=new ListUpdateAction();
        message.getGroup(1,noPartyEntitlements);//FieldNotFound Exception is thrown

    }

    @override
    public void fromApp(Message message,SessionID sessionId)throws Exception
    {
       crack(message,sessionId);
    }


}
```

Comment: Retrieving repeating groups is definitely working. It would be good if you added the code that you are using to retrieve the groups.

Comment: There is no way that this question can be answered with the little information provided.

Comment: This is regarding a custom message that was created by adding the message components and groups to the 50sp2.modified.xml, followed by building the jar. On Rephrasing the question, it would stand as,  how to extract the repeating groups from a custom message that was generated using quickfixj?

Comment: Actually in the same way as you would do from a normal message. Please show the code where you try to extract the repeating group along with a example message.

Comment: public void onMessage(MySampleMessage message,SessionID sessionId)throws Exception
    {
        MySampleMessage.NoPartEntitlements noPartyEntitlements=new MySampleMessage.NoPartEntitlements();
        ListUpdateAction listUpdateAction=new ListUpdateAction();
        message.getGroup(1,noPartyEntitlements);//FieldNotFound Exception is thrown

    }